# ios swift 3 delete contents of each cell when reloading tableView

Tags: ios, swift3

I am creating a quizApp using `DLRadioButton` with a label in each cell of `tableView`, the label is set from the `storyBoard`(with a tag) but I have set radioButtons programmatically for better design when I click next button to pass to next question new Radiobutton overlaps with the old Radiobutton

**here is the first question**

[image]

**here is the second image**

[image]

**Below is my code**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    var reponse = rep[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


     let content:UILabel=cell.viewWithTag(111) as! UILabel
    //var ra:UIButton=cell.viewWithTag(112) as! UIButton

    content.text=reponse["rep"] as? String
    content.sizeToFit()
    let repiii = reponse["rep"] as? String

   // var radio = DLRadioButton()
    if (self.type=="case à cocher"){
       // cell.contentView.delete(radioButtons)
        let frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 20, width: 200, height: 40)
       let squareButton = self.createRadioButton(frame: frame, title:repiii!, color:  UIColor.red,compt: squareButtons.count,sqaure:1);

        squareButtons.append(squareButton)
         cell.contentView.addSubview(squareButton)
    }
    else{
        let frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 20, width: 200, height: 40)

       let radioButton = self.createRadioButton(frame: frame, title:repiii!, color:  UIColor.blue,compt: radioButtons.count,sqaure:0);

       //radioButton.isMultipleSelectionEnabled = true
        print(radioButtons.count)
        radioButtons.append(radioButton)
     cell.contentView.addSubview(radioButton)
    }

    return cell
}
```

any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: You should not add subviews in `cellForRowAt`.  You should add the subview in your cell subclass.  You can then remove any added subviews in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for your response, I will try that

Comment: This is true and correct (and a best practice) if he had used a UITableView subclass

Comment: @iGenio unfortunately I haven't used UITableView subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, just after the line

```
let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
```

add this:

```
for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperView()
}
```

Comment: It should be `cell.contentView` not `cell`.

Comment: thnx for replying , when I added the loop I have got the following error Type 'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'sequence' I am trying to solve this issue :)